# App taking more time to login and taking more time to load data ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on ionic app.when i run app in android its fine. but when i build in ios device. its taking more time to load page and still taking more time in landing screen itself.

And in xcode i got this error in console.:

```
Resetting plugins due to page load.
```

Things i did :

1. Removed platform and added again
2. Added this line in `index.html`
   `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`
3. Changed the wifi connection.
   4.Quit xcode and done quit ios device.

But also i am facing same loading problem for long time.please help me out.

Thanks.